# Rails 3.2.5: Simple issue with search, need to return 'No Results Found' if nothing is found

Tags: ruby-on-rails, search, conditional-statements

I've looked at a few Railscasts and I know this is pretty simple but can't get it set up.

The actual SEARCH itself is working OK.

If I type in say, 'we' for example, it returns all the results with 'we' in it. Fair enough.

In my listing.rb file I have

```
  def self.search(search)
    s =  "%#{search}%"
    if search
      find(:all, :conditions => ["comments LIKE ? or doctor LIKE ? or website LIKE ? or     
      url LIKE ? or date LIKE ?", s, s, s, s, s])
    else
      find(:all)
    end
  end
```

In my listings_controller file I have:

```
def index
  @listings = Listing.search(params[:search_text])
end
```

So in the else portion I obviously don't want find(:all)

What would be the coding equivalent of return none or find none? return nil?

If you are in the form itself and it's blank and you hit enter, it should return nothing and it should say "No Results Found" or something like that.

Would the notice itself have to be in the controller, I mean couldn't I do like a render :text => 'No results found' or something?

or something like

```
elsif
  search.blank? 
  render [:index], flash[:notice] = 'No Results Found'
end
```

I know this is pretty simple but been out of the coding game for a bit, and relatively new to RoR in general.

Any input is greatly appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I don't think code has to be in controller

```
 def self.search(search)
    s =  "%#{search}%"
    if search
      find(:all, :conditions => ["comments LIKE ? or doctor LIKE ? or website LIKE ? or     
      url LIKE ? or date LIKE ?", s, s, s, s, s])
    else
      nil
    end
  end
```

and in view

```
<% if @listings.present? %>
 //some code here 
<% else %>
  <p>No results found</p>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Hi Salil thanks for the reply. So the view thing definitely helps and that is simple. So now if I'm in the form and type some random junk like 'asdnadasdad' nothing is returned and it says 'No Results Found'. Ok cool. BUt now my question is if I typed NOTHING in the search form, (as in it was blank and I hit enter), how would I get it to then return nothing and say No Results found?

Answer (score 0):

Try this changed as per your code

```
def self.search(search)
    s =  "%#{search}%"
    if search
      where("comments like (?) or doctor like (?)",s,s)
    else
     all
    end
  end
```

Comment: Sorry Amar isn't that doing the exact same thing as before, just written a bit differently?

Comment: oh instead of all in else set empty array[] or nil